# How to avoid conflicts when generating IR codes in yacc?

Tags: c, yacc

```
%nonassoc NO_ELSE
%nonassoc ELSE

stmt_conditional
     : IF '(' expr { show_if_begin($3); } ')' stmt_compound { show_if_end(); } %prec NO_ELSE
     | IF '(' expr { show_if_begin($3); } ')' stmt_compound { show_if_else(); }  ELSE stmt_compound { show_if_end(); }
```

Since `stmt_compound` will generate IRs, `show_if_begin()` should be in front of `stmt_compound`. However, this will cause reduce/reduce conflicts in yacc. How to solve this problem?

**EDITED**

This is what I've tried, but it didn't work.

```
stmt_conditional
     : stmt_cond_if { show_if_end(); } %prec NO_ELSE
     | stmt_cond_if { show_if_else(); } ELSE stmt_compound { show_if_end(); }
     ;

stmt_cond_if
     : IF '(' expr { show_if_begin($3); } ')' stmt_compound
```

Comment: Try to factor out the common part of the two kinds of if.

Comment: I did, but it got worse and worse. More conflict warnings popped up.

Comment: Show what you have tried.

Comment: Is `stmt_compound` include `stmt_conditional` or via some steps include `stmt_conditional`?

Comment: Yes. `stmt_compound` has `stmt`, and `stmt` has `stmt_conditional`

Comment: What is the lexical token seen with `NO_ELSE`?

Comment: Nothing. It's just a dummy variable to handle the dangling-else problem.

Comment: If nothing is seen with `NO_ELSE`, then nothing can be decided. Hence you do not handle the dangling else.

Comment: @KevinDong made an important update to the answer, you are welcome to take a look!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why your variant doesn't work is that you need infinite lookakead to distinguish between the two kinds of if statement. When your parser looks at an IF token, it has no idea whether it will see ELSE or NO_ELSE, or when to expect one if those, but it has to decide where to shift *now* in order to process the expression.

The solution is to factor out more common stuff so that the decision is made exactly when it's needed.

```
 stmt_conditional
     : stmt_cond_if { ... } else_part
     ;

 else_part
     : %prec NO_ELSE
     | ELSE stmt_compound { ... }
     ;
```

In theory, the parser generator should be able to refactor these rules automatically, but code blocks **in the middle of the rule** prevent `yacc` from doing so. Even empty code blocks in otherwise identical rules prevent them from being flattened out. That's because `yacc` sees the contents of code blocks as black boxes. It has no idea what these actions *mean* and has to assume they all might mean different things, even if the text is identical.

You can verify that when you remove the actions, the conflict disappears. Of course a `yacc` grammar without actions is less useful.

Naturally this factoring-out unifies your actions for THEN that originally were distinct for else and no-else variants. There is no way around this. You have to write an action that is good for both cases.

**Edit** In practice, such code blocks are handled by `yacc` by creating a new invisible rule and a new non-terminal for each mid-rule action. Quoth the yacc page:

> Actions that do not terminate a rule are actually handled by Yacc by manufacturing a new nonterminal symbol name, and a new rule matching this name to the empty string. The interior action is the action triggered off by recognizing this added rule.

It's these invisible rules that actually cause conflicts in your grammar. So another solution would be to leave the rules proper as is, but move actions to the end of their respective rules. I personally still like to factor out common parts manually. -- **end edit**.

Without `%prec` there would be a shift/reduce warning, because

```
if (x)
  if (y)
    do_something
  else
    do_something_else
```

is ambiguous: when the parser sees `else`, it doesn't know whether it belongs to the inner `if` (shift) or the outer one (reduce). The default behaviour is to shift, which is what we normally want. `%prec` makes this explicit and eliminates the warning.

Note this still may interfere with the rest of your grammar. If you can change your syntax I would suggest switching from C-like compound-statement-based syntax to an ENDIF-based one as found in e.g. Ada.

Comment: Could I replace `NO_ELSE` with `epsilon`? There is no token for `NO_ELSE`.

Comment: @KevinDong You will get a shift/reduce conflict then, which is sorta OK (that's how C works).

Comment: "_... factor out more common stuff so that the decision is made exactly when it's needed..._": Note that all non-terminal rules are flattened out in the parsing/state tables. Just equivalent to not factoring out.

Comment: The shift/reduce warnings are eliminated while replacing `/* epsilon */` (or `NO_ELSE` above) with `%prec NO_ELSE`

Comment: Sorry, didn't realise you are using NO_ELSE only for %prec. Will update.

Comment: N.m., this is basically the result of function `cpfir` in `y1.c` which ignores all non-terminal productions to calculate array 'pfirst' with the lookahead set of each nonterminal. See also Aho, Sethi & Ulman (if I spelled their names right).

Comment: @PaulOgilvie this is all fine and dandy, but can you produce a working yacc grammar without refactoring? I'm a simple man, I can't.

Comment: N.m., (sorry, been out for lunch), your solution is exactly the same as the original; just substitute it back.  If your solution "works" then there is another difference that we don't see. There is no room in these comments for more details; I suggest we leave it at this.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie I have tested refactored vs non-refactored grammar. Refactored works, non-refactored doesn't. There is nothing there I can't see. If you think this is wrong, post your own answer.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie The full unfactored yacc-ready grammar is [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e2a72e8f1d45984d), the factored-out one is [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9086d1f53223eb64). You are welcome to explain what exactly I did wrong. Or perhaps it's all Aho's fault.

Comment: n.m, I think I see. In one version there are two codeblocks `{ show_if_begin($3); }` and although they are the same code, yacc sees them as two _different_ blocks and so does in that version not know which of the two codeblocks to execute and signals a reduce/reduce conflict.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Exactly. Any two code blocks count as different even if they contain identical code, because yacc cannot really verify that their meaning is identical. Even if you reduce all blocks to `{}` there will be a conflict. Only removing code blocks eliminates the conflict (but then the grammar suddenly becomes not that useful). I had to mention that in the answer!

Comment: @PaulOgilvie I've learned a new thing or two today too, so my thanks go out to you as well.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie It's actually even more interesting than that. I've made an update.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133385/discussion-between-paul-ogilvie-and-n-m).